# Existe alguna herramienta o modo de alojar librerías js en Google cloud?

Tags: javascript, css, aplicación-web, hosting, google-cloud-platform

Quisiera saber si es posible alojar librerías, css, etc y enlazarlas a mis aplicaciones desarrolladas en Google Appscript.
Por ejemplo: subí imágenes a Google Storage y puedo usarlas para mostrarlas en un dashboard generado en javascript con GAS y HTML pero cuando hago lo mismo con archivos css o js y los enlazo de la siguiente forma:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://storage.googleapis.com/databaselhh.appspot.com/Librerias/Bootstrap/3.3.7/bootstrap.min.js">
```

Se ejecuta solo la primera parte de bootstrap pero no obtiene las fuentes, iconos y otros elementos. Cuál debería ser al forma correcta de alojar estas librerías?.
Muchas gracias en antemano

Nota: lo de bootstrap es solo un ejemplo lo necesito para cargar librerías propias.
He intentado con CDN de Google o Github pero no sé de dónde obtener la dirección para construir el link

Comment: Te diría que verifiques los `paths` a la `fonts`, porque por ejemplo, el archivo `https://storage.googleapis.com/databaselhh.appspot.com/Librerias/Bootstrap/3.3.7/bootstrap.min.css` existe, pero al intentar incluir las fuentes `../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot`, estas no existen. Entiendo que el archivo `.css` originalmente esta en la carpeta `css` y es por eso que no andan las rutas a las fuentes.

Comment: Mil gracias. Pequeño detalle